# How to send a JSON body in a cross-domain POST request with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Building on top of the question, [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript), is there a way to create that request with a JSON body, instead of the `name=value` params of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with jQuery, you can use something similar to this, and specifiy that the data is json through the contentType-option:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/your-taget.php",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: "your JSON",
  success: function(data){
    // Do something here on success
  }
});
```

**Update:**

Notice that if you are making a cross-domain request, and intend to return JSON from the server back to the client as well, then you need to send the data from the server to the client as JSONP - see [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) article for instance. Otherwise you will conflict with the browsers [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Due to browser security limitations, cross-domain ajax requests are not allowed. Thus, the jQuery ajax method doesn't help in this case. Also, JSONP doesn't do a POST request and doesn't contain any of the data in request BODY.

Comment: You are right of course, my bad, what confused me about the cross-domain request was the crossDomain option of jQuery.ajax(). Can anyone explain the purpose of that option?